Bash: Jump to the next iteration of a while loop without waiting for the command in the loop to exit
I am trying to write a little script which does the following:

Launch the PDF slideshow viewer impress!ve which can display all PDF files inside a folder page after page in a slideshow.
Watch the folder for changes (adding or deleting files).
On change, restart the viewer to pick up the modified folder contents.
Continue watching the folder for changes.

So far it looks like this:
#!/bin/bash

TESTPATH="/some/path/"

while true; do
    inotifywait -e create,delete,moved_from -r "$TESTPATH" && \
        echo "DEBUG: Event detected!" && pkill -f /usr/bin/impressive || true && impressive -a 10 -w "$TESTPATH*.pdf"
done

However I am stuck with the following issue: Once impressive has been started for the first time, it is being executed permanently and the loop is stuck inside this first iteration and inotifywait won't continue monitoring till impressive isn't killed by hand. I'd like to jump to the next iteration of the while loop directly after the launch of impressive, without waiting for it to exit.
I tried putting a nohup in front of the impressive call but it lead to my RAM getting full in a second and my machine freezing...
How can I solve this issue?
Solution thanks to hints by Barmar and Fravadona:
#!/bin/bash

TESTPATH="/some/path/"

inotifywait -m "$TESTPATH" -e moved_to -e moved_from -e delete |
    while read -r directory action file; do
            {
                echo "DEBUG: Event detected!" && pkill -f /usr/bin/impressive || true && impressive -a 10 -w "$TESTPATH*.pdf" &
            }
    done


Run impressive in the background with &. That's how you run a program without waiting for it to finish.

@Bamrmar: Turns out that actually the & lead to the system freeze. It happens within just a few seconds and I cannot really debug it...

I don't know what impressive does, maybe it's related to that.

If you get many consecutive notifications, you'll keep starting and killing impressive.

I now figured out, it just starts impressive with each iteration of the loop instead of watching the folder and only start it after an event has been caught. Since each instance of impressive takes some 100MB of RAM, the RAM quickly fills up and the machine freezes.

Sorry, I messed up, it's the same without the -m option though. I'll remove it from the initial question!

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific for the proper way to loop with inotifywait.

I combined this other way to loop with the grouping as proposed by Fravadona and now it almost works! The only problem is now that if I move in several files at once, it launches impressive several times in one go and they don't get killed but rather run in parallel. But I think, I'll better open a new question for this second issue! Thanks!

You might want to run the impressive command asynchronously. And did you know that you can group commands in curly-brackets?
#!/bin/bash

TESTPATH="/some/path/"

while true
do
    inotifywait -e create -e delete -e moved_from -r "$TESTPATH" && {
        echo "DEBUG: Event detected!"
        kill %
        impressive -a 10 -w "$TESTPATH"*.pdf &
    }
done

remark: I constrained the kill to the impressive process of the previous iteration, and moved the glob out of the double-quotes (for it to get expanded)

For some reason, after grouping the commands with curly brackets, none of the commands inside the curly brackets get executed. inotifywait reports an event but still, not even the echo line is shown...

It means that inotifywait terminates with an exit status different from 0, probably 1, which should mean: An error occurred in execution of the program, or an event occurred which was not being listened for.; good thing that the following commands are grouped in curly-bracket or else impressive would always run because of the || true

I see! But without the braces inotifywait ran correctly (at least once...) and I don't understand how this is different now.

The difference is that now impressive only runs when inotifywait terminates successfully. Before, impressive was always launched after inotifywait termination. Not sure what the reason is for inotifywait to fail; what did it capture?

It captured a "CREATE" event for example.

I think you need to use inotifywait -e create -e delete -e moved_from -r "$TESTPATH" && ...

I now tried the variant proposed by Barmar in the comments to the original question and combined it with the grouping and now it works! I attached a working proposal to the original question. The only problem is now that if I move in several files at once, it launches impressive several times in one go and they don't get killed but rather run in parallel. But I think, I'll better open a new question for this second issue! Thanks!

The issue is that impressive is running in the foreground blocking the loop from continuing. If you want the loop to continue directly after the launch of impressive you have start impressive  in the background.
You can do that by adding a & after the command:
#!/bin/bash

TESTPATH="/some/path/"

while true; do

inotifywait -m -e create,delete,moved_from -r "$TESTPATH" &&
echo "DEBUG: Event detected!" && pkill -f /usr/bin/impressive || true && impressive -a 10 -w "$TESTPATH*.pdf" &
done


Turns out that actually the & lead to the system freeze. It happens within just a few seconds and I cannot really debug it...

Yes you are right. Sorry for the confusion

No worries, it was actually part of the solution!
